# Как элементы БД отображать в виде ссылок Java Spring?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-mvc

Занимаюсь изучением `Java` и `Spring`. Делаю небольшой проект по сокращению ссылок (например, [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) вида gg и т.д.). Реализовал добавление ссылок и их вывод. Но после вывода данные ссылки некликабельны. Пытался использовать `hyperlink`, но из этого в итоге ничего не вышло. Как ссылки из БД (`MySQL`) сделать кликабельными?

Репозиторий и класс с конструкторами, геттерами и сеттерами не указывал.

Вот мой код

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

    DB db = new DB();

    @Autowired
    private LinkRepository linkRepository;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String link(Model model) {
        Iterable<Links> links = linkRepository.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("title", "Страница с ссылками");
        model.addAttribute("link", links);
        return "link";
    }

    @GetMapping("/uslugi")
    public String uslugi(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("title", "Страница с услугами");
        return "uslugi";
    }

    @PostMapping("/-add")
    public String linkAdd(@RequestParam String long_link, @RequestParam String short_link, Model model) {
        Links links = new Links(short_link, long_link);
        linkRepository.save(links);

        return "redirect:/";
    }
}
```

DB

```
import java.sql.*;

public class DB {

    private final String HOST = "localhost";
    private final String PORT = "3306";
    private final String DB_NAME = "spring";
    private final String LOGIN = "root";
    private final String PASS = "root";

    private Connection dbConn = null;


    private Connection getDbConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        String connStr = "jdbc:mysql://" + HOST + ":" + PORT + "/" + DB_NAME +
                "?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC";
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");

        dbConn = DriverManager.getConnection(connStr, LOGIN, PASS);
        return dbConn;
    }

    public void isConnected() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        dbConn = getDbConnection();
        System.out.println(dbConn.isValid(1000));
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.java10</groupId>
    <artifactId>serving-web-content</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>java10</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>



    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin><plugin><groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId><artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId><configuration><source>10</source><target>10</target></configuration></plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Html, если нужно

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>

    <header class="d-flex flex-column flex-md-row align-items-center p-3 px-md-4 mb-3 bg-white border-bottom shadow-sm">
        <p class="h5 my-0 me-md-auto fw-normal">Java</p>
        <nav class="my-2 my-md-0 me-md-3">
            <a class="p-2 text-dark" href="/">Главная</a>
            <a class="p-2 text-dark" href="/uslugi">Про нас</a>
        </nav>
    </header>

<body>

<div class="container mt-5">
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
        <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jpaDialect" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect"/>


    <h3 class="mt-2">Все отзывы</h3>

    <div th:each="row : ${link}">
        <h4 class="mt-2" th:text="${row.long_link}"/>
        <h4 th:text="${row.short_link}"/>
    </div>
    <h1 class="mt-5" th:text="${title}"/>

    <form th:action="@{/-add}" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="long_link"
               placeholder="Введите ссылку" class="form-control"><br>
        <input type="text" name="short_link"
               placeholder="Введите короткую ссылку" class="form-control"><br>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Добавить</button>
    </form>
</div>
</body>

    <footer class="pt-4 my-md-5 pt-md-5 border-top">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 col-md">
                <small class="d-block mb-3 text-muted">©2021    Все права защищены</small>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
</html>
```

Comment: Приложите, пожалуйста, к вопросу шаблоны (Thymeleaf/JSP).

Comment: Дополнил свой вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам необходимо использовать `<a href="url">...</a>`:

```
<div th:each="row : ${link}">
    <a th:href="${row.short_link}">${row.long_link}</a>
</div>
```